# In dekker's algorithm, can i remove the last instruction flag[ i ] = false?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, operating-system, scheduling

Considering two processes, 0 and 1, and the program for the process 0:

```
do
{

flag[0]= true;

while(flag[1]==true)
{
  if(turn!=0)   
   {

    flag[0] = false; 

    while(turn!=0); 

    flag[0] = true;    

   }

}

 // CS

turn = 1;     

flag[0] = false; 
}while(true);
```

What is the purpose of the last line flag[0] = false? Why can't it be removed? It will go back to the first line flag[0] = true and nothing happened because of it.

Answer (score 1):

The `while(true)` loop is not part of Dekker's algorithm.

The `flag[0]=false` allows process 1 to enter the criticial section while process 0 is off doing unrelated things.  If process 0 is continuously re-entering he critical section in an infinite loop, then it's not necessary, since process 0 will never be off doing unrelated things.

That's not a common scenario, though.